# Editing words in a string using a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

This is what i've written so far:

```
for /l %%x in (Veronica, Nils, Mike, Tom) do (
set word=%%x
set str="My name is Name"
call set str=%%str:Name=%word%%%
echo %str% >> names.txt
)
```

Unfortunately the only output is:

```
ECHO is on.
ECHO is on.
ECHO is on.
```

in an infinite loop.

Any ideas on where I've gone wrong/

Comment: It's a standard `For` loop you need not a `For /L` and doublequotes are your friend, don't be afraid to use them. You've got the string `name` in there twice too and you can `Call Echo` to bypass an unneeded, `Set`. And you do know that you can use `For %%A In (Veronica, Nils, Mike, Tom) Do Echo My name is %%A`, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

Windows command processor replaces **all** occurrences of `%variable%` within a command block starting with `(` and ending with matching `)` by current value of referenced environment variable before the command is executed using the command block. See [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/) This command block handling by `cmd.exe` can be seen by running the batch file from within a command prompt window instead of double clicking on the batch file with `@echo off` removed or modified to `@echo ON` or commented out temporarily until the batch file is working as expected.

The help output on running `set /?` in a command prompt window explains on an **IF** and a **FOR** example when and how to use [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) which is the preferred method to access an environment variable value within a command block being defined or modified in same command block.

The other solution is referencing the environment variable using the syntax `%%variable%%` and using command **CALL** to force a double parsing of this command line by `cmd.exe`. In this case `%%` is modified on parsing entire command block to `%` on both sides of the referenced environment variable and later on execution of command **CALL** the remaining `%variable%` is parsed once again and substituted by current value of the referenced variable.

In posted batch code the environment variable `str` is not defined above **FOR** command line with the command block. For that reason `echo %str% >> names.txt` is on parsing the entire command block modified by `cmd.exe` to `echo  >> names.txt` before **FOR** is executed at all and so **ECHO** just outputs three times the current status.

Also the command line `call set str=%%str:Name=%word%%%` does not work because of `word` is not defined before **FOR** command line with the command block and therefore `%word%` is substituted already by nothing resulting in the command line `call set str=%str:Name=%` being finally executed three times on loop execution.

The next error is usage of **FOR** option `/L` for this loop. The help output on running `for /?` in a command prompt window explains for `for /L`:

> ```
> FOR /L %variable IN (start,step,end) DO command [command-parameters]
>
>     The set is a sequence of numbers from start to end, by step amount.
>     So (1,1,5) would generate the sequence 1 2 3 4 5 and (5,-1,1) would
>     generate the sequence (5 4 3 2 1)
> ```

It should be clear after reading this help that `/L` is not the right option for this task.

The next mistake is that string substitutions done with command **SET** or directly by `cmd.exe` on parsing the command line are always applied case-insensitive. The string assigned to environment variable `str` contains `name` and `Name` which are both replaced on string substitution. That is not really wanted here.

Then there is a big difference on using `set variable="value"` or on using `set "variable=value"`. The latter is the better as explained in detail in answer on [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564)

Finally the space character left to redirection operator `>>` is also output by command **ECHO** resulting in a trailing space in the file. Therefore the redirection operator `>>` should not be separated by a space from string to write into the file.

First working code for the example uses delayed environment variable expansion:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
del names.txt 2>nul
set "str=My name is #name#"
for %%I in (Veronica, Nils, Mike, Tom) do echo !str:#name#=%%~I!>>names.txt
endlocal
```

Second working code for the example uses the **CALL** trick:

```
@echo off
del names.txt 2>nul
set "str=My name is #name#"
for %%I in (Veronica, Nils, Mike, Tom) do call echo %%str:#name#=%%~I%%>>names.txt
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `set /?`

See also the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at `delayedexpansion` run from cmdline `setlocal /?` to see how it is enabled and `set /?` to see the explanation of it:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%x in (Veronica, Nils, Mike, Tom) do (
  set "word=%%x"
  set "str=My name is repl"
  call set "str=%%str:repl=!word!%%"
  echo !str!
)
```

To make the script cleaner looking, you might even want to either add the names to a variable which can be updated, without having to extend your for loop, by calling the variable:

```
@echo off
set "names=Veronica,Nils,Mike,Tom"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%x in (%names%) do (
  set "word=%%x"
  set "str=My name is repl"
  call set "str=%%str:repl=!word!%%"
  echo !str!
)
```

Note that we replace the `%` with `!` where we need variables expanded. Also not that I set my double quotes starting before the variable name in each `set`

Answer (score 0):

Some point in your code:

**Errors:**

- The `FOR /L %var IN (start,step,end)` syntax is used is to iterate through a sequence of numbers from `start` to `end` incrementing by the amount which is specified by `step` So the loop variable (`%var`) represents the current number in sequence.
  But you want to iterate through a set of strings, for that purpose you have to use the naked variant of the `FOR` command (`FOR` without any switches). The documentation says that it is for iterating through a set of files, but as long as the strings does not contain the wildcard characters `*?` it can be safely used to iterate through set of strings.
  So as the first step to correct the code, the `/L` switch must be removed the `FOR` command:
  `for %%x in (Veronica, Nils, Mike, Tom) do ...`
- Normal variable expansions; Also known as percent variable expansion, occurs before the code actually get executed, So in a block of code, you can only reliably use percent expansion for the variables which were defined before entering that block of code, Any modification to variables in the same block will not be visible by percent expansion (`%var%`) because it has been expanded to whatever it was before entering the block.
  To overcome this limitation you can either double up the percents around the variable and prefix the command with `CALL`: `call echo %%var%%` or use delayed variable expansion:`echo !var!`
  So the next step would be to replace `echo %str%` by `call echo %%str%%`.
- The variable substitutions are not case sensitive, So in the substitution `%str:Name=Vernica%`, because the `str` variable contains two occurrence the the substring "name" (`"My name is Name"`) it will replace both and the result will be `My Veronica is Veronica`. For the replacement of the Name part you have to use a substring which is unique within the main string:
  `set "str=My name is $Name"`
  `call set str=%%str:$Name=%%x%%`

  Also note the direct use of `FOR` variable `%%x` in the substitution. There is no need to assign `%%x` to another variable like what you did with `set word=%%x`. And even if you, it will not work because in `call set str=%%str:Name=%word%%%` the variable `%word%` has already being replaced by batch parser with whichever value it had before entering the `FOR` block.

Summing up the above points, a working code can written like this

```
for %%x in (Veronica, Nils, Mike, Tom) do (
    set "str=My name is $Name"
    call set str=%%str:$Name=%%x%%
    call echo %%str%% >>"names.txt"
)
```

The above works correctly and produces the desired result, but it is extremely inefficient and can be optimized further to produce a more efficient, faster, shorter and cleaner code which will be described in the following section.

**Inefficiencies:**

Continuing with the corrected code in the last section

- The `str` variable is a static variable, that is on each iteration of the loop you initialize it with the same string `My name is $Name` So it can be moved outside of the loop and initialized just once.
- Since you are using the substituted string only once to write it to output device, the `set` and `echo` can be combined to single command doing both at once: `call echo %%str:$Name=%%x%%`
- The redirection used inside the loop (`>>"names.txt"`), So on each iteration of the loop, the file `names.txt` will be opened, written to, and closed. This is very inefficient, think of the loop that does this tens of thousands of time. The whole `FOR` loop can be placed inside a redirected block, So the file `names.txt` will be opened only once on when the loop starts and closed when the loop in finished.
- It is better to enclose the name items between quotes, should they contain any spaces or special characters the code will not affected. Actually it is not an inefficiency but rather a best practice recommendation.

**Final result**

Without delayed expansion:

```
set "str=My name is $Name"
(for %%x in ("Veronica", "Nils", "Mike", "Tom") do call echo %%str:$Name=%%~x%%)>"names.txt"
```

With delayed expansion:

```
set "str=My name is $Name"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(for %%x in ("Veronica", "Nils", "Mike", "Tom") do echo !str:$Name=%%~x!)>"names.txt"
endlocal
```

In comparison between using `CALL` or `DelayedExpansion`

- `CALL` is very slow, `DelayedExpansion` is much faster.
- `DelayedExpansion` will fail if the names contain `!`
- `CALL` will fail if the names contain any one the `&|<>` characters, unless you enclose them in quotes when using `echo`. e.g. `call echo "%%str:$Name=%%~x%%"`.
  Of course this can't happen with human names, but with generic strings.